# Unable to receive data returned by a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project. I have two files `contact.js` and `functions.js`.

In `contact.js` file

```
import {getUserContacts} from './functions.js';

 useEffect(() => {
    let temp=getUserContacts();
    console.log(temp);
  }, [])
```

In `functions.js` file

```
export const getUserContacts = () => {
  const contactDetailsArr = [];

  db.collection("users").doc(userId).get()
    .then(docs => {

      const contactsObject = docs.data().contacts;

      for (let contact in contactsObject) {

        db.collection("users").doc(contact).get()
          .then(userDetail => {
            contactDetailsArr.push({
              userId: contact,
              lastMessage: contactsObject[contact].lastMsg,
              time: contactsObject[contact].lastMsgTime,
              email: userDetail.data().emailId,
              active: userDetail.data().active,
              img: userDetail.data().imageUrl
            })

          })
      }
      
      return contactDetailsArr;

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })

}
```

As one can see in the `functions.js` when I console `contactDetails` I am able to see the data. But in `contact.js` when I console the returned data I get `undefined`.

Comment: Because `contactDetails` is undefined?

Comment: The issue could happen in `getUserContacts()` function logic that cause `contactDetails` is `undefined`.

Comment: @HuyPham @robertkelp, but the statement ``console.log(contactDetails)`` before returning the ``contactDetails`` is showing the result I want to pass

Comment: We can't really help until you elaborate what `getUserContacts` is doing ...

Comment: @KcH, I have shared the full ``getUserContacts`` code. let me know if more information is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic of `getUserContacts()` does not `return` anything that's why you get `undefined`. Try to add `return` as below.

```
export const getUserContacts = () => {
  const contactDetailsArr = [];
  return db.collection("users").doc(userId).get()
    .then(docs => {
      const contactsObject = docs.data().contacts;
      for (let contact in contactsObject) {
        db.collection("users").doc(contact).get()
          .then(userDetail => {
            contactDetailsArr.push({
              ...
            })
          })
      }
      return contactDetailsArr;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any data. What you should to HuyPham did since it returns a promise. From there, you can do temp.then(res => console.log(rrs))

Answer (score 0):

You might have this result if there's a delay in your function logic

Comment: This can go as a comment, as it is just that "it might be a thing" :)

Comment: @KcH, Thanks for helping but could you elaborate what you mean

Comment: @Abby It's to vporel, to keep the "answer" as a comment as it is :) ///

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I hope your

> //function logic

done have any async stuff, otherwise

> contactDetails

would be undefined at the time you call

> getUserContacts